# Spritekit 2.5d how to to animate objects getting closer (E.g. Temple Run)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make some SKShapeNodes look like theyre getting closer to the user, from a far away point. This is what I have so far:

[image]

What I'm doing is scaling the shape nodes over time, and applying an imuplse to them. The problem is they don't look like theyre getting closer because the distance between each shape is getting smaller. How would I go 
about doing this?

Edit: I guess a good way to think about this is, I'm trying to make the same effect as temple run, where the coins get closer to the user as he runs towards them.

Comment: Why not just do the background in Scene Kit so that you do not have to worry about matrix manipulation.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon do you know any good scenekit tutorials I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The nodes need to get faster to achieve this effect. So you could multiply their velocity vector with a factor in the update method.

Comment: I know lol, I'm asking how to do the math/what the formula is. I'm assuming it's a common problem.